# Converting React.lazy object to JSX element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading

I have a component called `GoogleMap.js`. I want to import it if user scrolls, so I made it lazy import but it doesn't return JSX. Instead it returns `React.lazy` object. So I cannot render it in JSX. How can I render it with in JSX. Also, if I use it like that, does it import react google map even though use doesn't scroll the page.

```
import React from 'react'
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const GoogleMapWrapper = styled.div`
    height: 40vh; 
    width: 60vw;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
`

function GoogleMap() {

    return (
        <GoogleMapWrapper>
            <GoogleMapReact
                bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'AIzaSyAER*******************zs0' }}
                defaultCenter={{
                    lat: -3.745,
                    lng: -38.523
                }}
                defaultZoom={3}
            >
                <div
                    lat={59.955413}
                    lng={30.337844}
                    text="My Marker"
                />
            </GoogleMapReact>
        </GoogleMapWrapper>
    )
}

export default GoogleMap
```

```
 useEffect(() => {
        if (isImported) {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollDetector)
            const GoogleMap = React.lazy(() => import('../../components/DynamicLandingPages/GoogleMap'))
            console.log("type:", typeof GoogleMap)
            console.log("OBJ:", GoogleMap)
            setGoogleMapComponent(GoogleMap)
        }
    }, [isImported])
```

Note: googleMapComponent is a react state. Set is its setter function.

```
<Suspense fallback={<GoogleMapWrapper />}>
    <googleMapComponent />
</Suspense>
```

Here is what it returns:

```
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.lazy), _status: -1, _result: null, _ctor: ƒ, …}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are abusing React state. You shouldn't keep components as state !
Also, this `<googleMapComponent />` is wrong. More details in [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).

Finally, is there any reason for using `React.lazy` in `useEffect` ?

It should be used something like this:

```
// some MyComponent.js file

// ... normal imports ...

const GoogleMap = React.lazy(() => import('../../components/DynamicLandingPages/GoogleMap'));

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <GoogleMap />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you need something to be rendered when you scroll to certain position, than you might want add some state - something like `isElementInViewport`, you need a piece of JS to actually figure that out and set that state to `true` when it happens and then you can do stuff like:

```
{isElementInViewport  
&& (Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
    <GoogleMap />
</Suspense>)}
```

Comment: I want to show a google Map in my website. But it is down and lots of users wont scroll down. So I want to import and render it only if user scrolls. So I thought detecting if user scrolled enough, and then Import the component and store it in react state so user wont have to import if dont scroll. Import in use effect only works one because it tries to detect one time that isImported turns to be true.

Comment: So, with your solution, even if user doesnt scroll down, my component and with it, google map will be imported as soon as user enters the website right?

Comment: Yes it solves some part of question like, rendering. But I want to not import if user doesnt scroll down. Does this solution provides that as well. For ex, if I do that at the top of the file,
const GoogleMap = React.lazy(()=>import('../../example.js')) and 
the conditional rendering below in jsx like you state. In this situation, does react import GoogleMap if isElementInView false?

Comment: @zan5959 React.lazy will automatically load the bundle containing your component when this component is first rendered. so if you don't render and as long as `isElementInViewport`  is `false` that won't happen - your bundle should not be loaded, feel free to test if that's the case :)

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I have tested and it works like you said! I have approved your answer above.